# Nested EnumMap using Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm starting with Java streams and during the lecture of effective programming book i found this piece of code:

```
    public enum Phase {
  SOLID, LIQUID, GAS;

  public enum Transition {
    MELT(SOLID, LIQUID), FREEZE(LIQUID, SOLID),
    BOIL(LIQUID, GAS), CONDENSE(GAS, LIQUID),
    SUBLIME(SOLID, GAS), DEPOSIT(GAS, SOLID);

    private final Phase from;
    private final Phase to;

    Transition(Phase from, Phase to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    private static final Map<Phase, Map<Phase, Transition>>
        m = Stream.of(values()).collect(groupingBy(t -> t.from,
            () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class),
            toMap(t -> t.to, t -> t,
                (x, y) -> y, () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class))));

    public static Transition from(Phase from, Phase to) {
        return m.get(from).get(to);
    }
  }
}
```

And I cannot understand how this EnumMap is created. The most difficult to understand for me is :

```
toMap(t -> t.to, t -> t,
                (x, y) -> y, () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class))));
```

Does anybody could explain it to me ?

Comment: This is a great example how you can use streams to turn your trivial code into unreadable mess. Although the functional programmers in the crowd might feel a slight tingle in their pants (not that they would care about Java's limited tools in that aspect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the code do:
You have a stream of elements, and want to group them by initial phase. Here the author chose to use a complex group by operation, which will *also* perform post-transformation of groupped data. This is where `toMap` function comes in. Once `groupingBy` collector starts buffering elements, it delegates to `mapTo` collector to build custom records for each group. Here, the author uses toMap to index phases by their *target* state: *to*.

So, let's decompose it :

```java
Stream.of(values())
   // Queries a result
   .collect(
       // Elements must be grouped using a key, extracted from each streamed value
       groupingBy(
           // Specify how to extract the grouping key
           t -> t.from,
            // Here, the author specifies himself how to create the group map,
            // to be sure it will use a custom enum-optimized key management.
            () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class),
            // Nest another collector, to transform the list of values 
            // of each group into something else. Note that toMap does not 
            // buffer a collection of values for a key. It is designed to 
            // map a key to each value. But, it allows user to merge  
            // merge conflicting values if needed.
            toMap(
                // Same than groupby, we specify how to extract key from value. 
                t -> t.to, 
                // Here, specify that the value associated to the key is the 
                // object we've extracted key from. Here, wwe could have changed
                // it to something else (a text representation, for example).
                t -> t,
                // toMap will bind one key to one value. We have to solve 
                // conflict ourself. Here, author decided to drop arbitrarily 
                // one of the values.
                (x, y) -> y,
                // As for groupby operator, author forces a map implementation 
                // dedicated to enum keys.
                () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class))));
```

Finally, official [stream collection documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) provide quite some explanation.

I'm not sure if my explanation is enough, you can give remarks in comments.

Comment: So example: FREEZE(LIQUID, SOLID).  **t** describe this object. Outer key map will be in this case **LIQUID** and inner key will be **SOLID**. **t -> t** means that we don't transform our object and leave as it is. **(x,y) -> y** means that we have values for outer and inner key and we have to choose one value, so we decided to choose value from inner map. Am I right or I understand it wrong ?

Comment: You're almost all right. The only slight difference is about **(x, y) -> y**. This lambda will be used *only* if *toMap* detects a conflict. That means that two Transitions in the same group (therefore with the same *from* phase), **also** have the same target phase *to*. In this particular example, I think it will never be used. However, the collection API ask user to give nonetheless, because it does not know dataset beforehand, so the author *must* provide a conflict resolution strategy, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

What is being create here is a Map of Maps that provide the Transition method when going from one state, to another.  If it were done without `lambdas` or `streams` it might look like the following:

```
    public static Map<Phase, Map<Phase, Transition>> init() {
        Map<Phase, Map<Phase,Transition>> outerMap = new EnumMap<>(Phase.class);
        for (Transition v : Transition.values()) {
            Map<Phase, Transition> innerMap = outerMap.get(v.from);
            if (innerMap == null) {
                innerMap = new EnumMap<>(Phase.class);
                outerMap.put(v.from, innerMap);
            }
            innerMap.put(v.to, v);
        }
        return outerMap;
    }
```

What follows is the Stream explanation.

Start with a `stream` of the `Transition` enum values.  In all cases here, `t` is a `Transition` type.

```
        public static Map<Phase, Map<Phase, Transition>> map = Stream
                .of(values())
```

Then they are collected into a `EnumMap` using the `Collectors.groupingBy()` method.  All the keys here will be taken from the `Transition.from` field.  The value for this outer map will be an `EnumMap`

```
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.from,
                        () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class),
```

Next, the downstream collector, now populates that newly created map with another map. The inner map will use the following.

- Transition.to field for keys - `t.to`
- The resulting Transition type for values which is just `t`

```
                        Collectors.toMap(t -> t.to, t -> t,
```

This next statement is simply a merge function and it isn't used in this particular application so a just chose a value.

```
                                (x, y) -> x,
```

Finally, specify a `Supplier` to for the type of `innerMap` to create.

```
                               () -> new EnumMap<>(Phase.class))));
```

When `Transition.from()` is invoked using arguments from the `Phase` enum the map is referenced to display the `Transition` process.